# Django wsgi error after upgrade from 1.11 to 2.0 (load_middleware: argument to reversed() must be a sequence)

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, django-2.0, django-middleware, django-wsgi

After upgrading from django 1.11 to 2.0 I got this error on my productive machine.

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=26504): Target WSGI script '/var/www/htdocs/myappdir/app_myapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=26504): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/htdocs/myappdir/app_myapp.wsgi'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/www/htdocs/myappdir/app_myapp.wsgi", line 13, in <module>
     application = django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()
   File "/var/www/priv/venv/myappdirpy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
     return WSGIHandler()
   File "/var/www/priv/venv/myappdirpy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 140, in __init__
     self.load_middleware()
   File "/var/www/priv/venv/myappdirpy3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 36, in load_middleware
     for middleware_path in reversed(settings.MIDDLEWARE):
 TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence
```

It seems to be a probleme with the settings.MIDDLEWARE option, but it looks correct. Here is the MIDDLEWARE part from my settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
    'wagtail.core.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
]
```

If I run "python3 manage.py runserver" directly on my productive machine, everything seems to work. But if I access the proejct through wsgi it is not working.

Any idea where to start?

Comment: did you update wagtail and if you are using apache with wsgi update the libapache2 from py2 to py3 by sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3

Comment: I run wagtail 2.1.0 which supports Django 2.0 and I allready use python3. Any other ideas?

Comment: can you post more of your settings.py the above code is proper also make sure you are loading proper settings file

Comment: Rebooting the hole system fixed this problem. Restarting apache or touching my .htaccess did not help ... Restarting apache should normally be enough or not?

Comment: You need touch wsgi.py also